# How to access matrix of pairs?

Tags: python

I'm iterating through a ndarray (returned by `calcOpticalFlowFarneback` - openCV) in the following way

```
for ((y, x, v), val) in np.ndenumerate(my_ndarray):
    print ("At row " , x , " and column " , y , " we have at index ", v, " the component ", val, ")")
```

and getting output like

```
('At row ', 0L, ' and column ', 0L, ' we have at index ', 0L, ' the component ', -1.539571e-05, ')')
('At row ', 0L, ' and column ', 0L, ' we have at index ', 1L, ' the component ', 0.21003947, ')')
```

since this is a matrix of pairs (each cell in the matrix has two components of a vector), is there a way I can access the values in the same loop as

```
for ((y, x), (val1, val2)) in np.ndenumerate(my_ndarray):
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not working
```

i.e. by skipping the 0-1 indexing altogether?

Unfortunately the code I tried above is not working

Comment: What do you mean by "matrix of pairs"? It's not, from what I see it's three-dimensional array, containing real numbers. Why you print third coordinate as "component" I have no idea.

Comment: "Matrix of pairs" seems to be something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024750/numpy-cant-build-a-2-d-array-of-tuples, but here you have 3-dimensional array. Can you show the code, which creates and initializes the matrix, please?

Comment: @user502144 I don't have it, it's returned by `calcOpticalFlowFarneback` (openCV). I'm editing the question to add more info

Comment: What's wrong with your first attempt? Even if the second one was working I don't see any difference from the first one. You still iterate over the 3D array and within each iteration you have access to the three indices (initially returned as a tuple) and the value. What do you think is the benefit of the 2nd approach?

Comment: @a_guest That I can use both values at the same time?

Comment: @Dean That's still not clear. Can you show some pseudo code for how you want to use them "at the same time"? Or describe in more detail? Secondly what happens here in your for loop is value unpacking (for tuples). Since the method in question returns a tuple containing the indices as first element (packed in another tuple) and the value as a second element you can only unpack those two elements at this stage. Further unpacking is then possible for the indices. But again, I really don't see how your 2nd approach is different, in both cases you have equally access to all those four values.